# Another word for component

Tags: single-word-requests, finance

I was wondering if someone could give a more appropriate word to use in the case below other than component.

> *This will allow a user to manage all **components** of the financial landscape.*

I need the "meaning" word that can replace **component** to include; people, groups of people, and organisations. I feel that the word component is too cold.

Bonus if you can give me a better word than **landscape**!

Comment: How about "aspects"?

Comment: If you're talking about persons (real or legal fiction), consider *stakeholders*.

Comment: A bit more context would be fine, but I personally vote for Xanne's suggestion: aspects.

Comment: Instead of components you can try factors, segments, elements or units. Instead of landscape you can try range, scene, view or field.

Comment: You could use 'entities' for 'components'. You could consider 'domain' for 'landscape'.

Comment: "every/all facet(s)" or "every/all piece(s)"

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***players*** as a substitute for *components* in your sentence:

> *This will allow a user to manage all the **players** of the financial landscape.*

This word is definitely not as cold as *components* and can include people, groups of people, and organizations (as requested by OP).

Some of the other suggestions like aspects, factors, and entities are just as cold if not colder than components.  Come on people!

BONUS:

Consider ***engine*** as a substitute for landscape.  I realize this introduces a mixed metaphor scenario but it removes the coldness:

> *This will allow a user to manage all the players of the financial **engine***.

Or, with engine instead of landscape I think components might work just fine...

> *This will allow a user to manage all the components of the financial **engine***.